# How to change icon in notification iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, local-storage

I am creating a navigation based application, in that there is function that will alert the user for some events that will occur.
For that we are using Push notification, i know how to implement push notification,

But My question is can i change the icon in notification centre when push notification comes?

Note: i am not talk about badge icon,

Check desired images of notificaiton centre:

[image]
 [image]

If not please provide reference for that.

Comment: no you can't change it it same as your app icon

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The layout and presentation of push notifications is defined by iOS you are able to supply an app icon that is always used with your push notifications (always the same) and the textual message. The icon you use must be based on the same app icon you use for the app itself. This is **part of the guidelines**.

Here is the reference for it

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/notifications/

Comment: Thanks for response, it would be great if you provide the apple doc refernce for it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/NotificationCenter.html

Comment: The link doesn't work. Here is the updated one: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/notifications/

Comment: Hi @Ramdhas, it was probably true back then but now you can see iMessage / TikTok that are passing user's profile picture in the notification icon. Do you have any idea how to achieve this in 2022 ? (EDIT : i have found the answer : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/implementing_communication_notifications)

Comment: @Tom3652, no idea. Have to check.

Comment: I have added the link towards the new documentation to achieve this

Comment: @Tom3652 hey have you been able to integrate it? im a lone jr programmer having so much difficulty figuring this out...

Comment: I am in the same situation @Chris but i am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to deliver push notification so i have raised a feature request / bug report there to ask about it and they are investigating.

Comment: @Tom3652 oh i see, i'm trying to see if it's possible via firebase cloud functions. if anything happens to make more sense regarding icon image changes, happy to hear more about it!

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. The push notification icon is something which you specify in the Icons list of your Info.plist. This cannot be changed for each notification.

Answer (score 1):

iOS displays the small version of your app icon in a banner, so that people can see at a glance which app is notifying them.

[Click here to read Apple Notification Guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/NotificationCenter.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot - can you specify what icon size does it use.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can change push notification icon but its recommended that you dont change the push notification icon so that user don't get confused from which app they are getting the notification.

In order to change the push notification icon, on the appicon set you need to change the spotlight icons.

AppIcon -> Change both spotlight icons.

[push notification icon change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beTyb.png)